# Can't install numpy or pygame with pip Python 3.6

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, pip, python-3.6

I recently upgraded to **Python 3.6** on **Windows 10** in order to use the newest formatting syntax for a text-based RPG game that I am programming currently.
The game requires the use of 2 external modules (`numpy` and `pygame`) to work.

I've tried the usual command `pip install module_name` in the `cmd` but it throws me an error message.

After browsing SO I've used the commands `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgade `pip` and it was at the latest version already.
I also used the command `pip install --upgrade wheel` and my `wheel` was upgraded to the latest version.
I also used the command `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and my `setuptools` was upgraded to the latest version.

I tried again, and still nothing. Neither module will install.

**EDIT:** I tried `easy_install module_name` with both `numpy` and `pygame` and neither of them were installed. I also tried `pip3.6 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org numpy` and that didn't work.

I've asked this as a seperate question since I've tried what was suggested in other SO questions and it hasn't worked. Plus, this concerns both `numpy` and `pygame` modules, and no other question does.

My error message for `pygame`:

```
C:\Users\zactheblackdragon>python -m pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Path for SDL not found.
    Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
    Path for FONT not found.
    Path for IMAGE not found.
    Path for MIXER not found.
    Path for PNG not found.
    Path for JPEG not found.
    Path for PORTMIDI not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
    Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

    If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
    the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


    Continuing With "setup.py"
    Error with the "Setup" file,
    perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ovlzq9si\pygame\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
        extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
      File "C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
        line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
      File "C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 410, in expand_makefile_vars
        s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
    TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ovlzq9si\pygame\
```

My error message for `numpy`:

```
C:\Users\zactheblackdragon>python -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.11.3.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ZACTHE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-i_43zwj2\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpm39rz3bgpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  Running from numpy source directory.
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1630: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  blas_info:
    libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1639: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1642: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    NOT AVAILABLE

  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  F2PY Version 2
  lapack_opt_info:
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  Complete output from command C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ZACTHE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-i_43zwj2\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Running from numpy source directory.

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
Failed to build numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ZACTHE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-i_43zwj2\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-dn2eq0_h-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last Numpy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1630: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1639: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1642: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\zactheblackdragon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\zactheblackdragon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ZACTHE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-i_43zwj2\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-dn2eq0_h-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ZACTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i_43zwj2\numpy\
```

Comment: Could you please share the error message you're getting?

Comment: @Mureinik see edited question.

Comment: read all the logs you got e.g. "libraries lapack not found", "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."

Comment: @mic4ael so i need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0?

Comment: @Arbiter, not only ;)

Comment: @mic4ael doesn't matter, i've reverted back to Python 3.4. Seems `pygame` hasn't got support yet. I'm sure the devs will have support within the next few months - `pygame` is a hugely popular module.

Comment: @Arbiter In this thread, they talk about shipping an updated version for 3.6 in the future (newest update was 24 days ago, which was the first update for 7 years...) https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5i4ado/pygame_192_finally_released_after_more_than_7/db5umrj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Download and install [Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).

Go to [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and download the .whl file that suits your Python and Windows version. In my case it's **pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl** since I use Python 3.6.0 and Windows 64bits. Paste the file in the Python folder (in my case it's C:\Python)

Next, while holding shift, right click the Python installation folder and choose "Open command window here". A cmd window will open.

Enter the following:

```
pip install setuptools

pip install wheel
```

After Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools is installed, install numpy with:

```
pip install numpy
```

If you downloaded **pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl**, install Pygame with:

```
pip install pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Or else change `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` to the name of the file you downloaded.

Before you enter the previous command, make sure the file you downloaded is in the Python folder *(in my case, C:\Python\pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl)* and you copied the whole file name including the .whl extension or else it won't work.

This should install both numpy and pygame.

Comment: How do you find the folder in which the `.whl` file should be placed?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the problem by using `cd "C:\Users\(MY_USERNAME)\Desktop"` to change my current directory to my desktop. I then placed the `.whl` file there and installed it with `pip install wheel_name.whl`.

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to install pygame on Windows 10, now just type:

```
pip install pygame
```

It automatically does it for you. You don't have to go to the sites and download the whl file anymore.